# Different styles for two jquery accordions in same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I have two jquery accordions in my page . One in the east and One in west panel .  Is it possible to style them differently ? Editing .ui-accordion related styles changes style of both the accordions . 
Is there a way to provide different styles for the two accordions ?

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can with some tricks.
All you have to do is override jQuery, UI and CSS for other accordion, something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/znw3e/).

Answer (score 1):

Simply add a different ID (or class) to both, then add them to the CSS selector. Alternatively, you can add an ID of a parent element. Ex:

```
.ui-accordion{...}
.ui-accordion div{...}
.ui-accordion .arrow{...}
```

becomes

```
#left-column .ui-accordion{...}
#left-column .ui-accordion div{...}
#left-column .ui-accordion .arrow{...}

#right-column .ui-accordion{...}
#right-column .ui-accordion div{...}
#right-column .ui-accordion .arrow{...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible now your define on extra id in your jQuery as like this

**HTML**

```
<div id="slider1" class="east">
   // some code of your html
</div>

<div id="slider2" class="east">
   // some code of your html
</div>
```

**Css**

```
#slider1.east .somecss{
 // css style as like your requirement 
 }

#slider2.east .somecss{
 // css style as like your requirement 
 }
```

Comment: You have (or try to have) two elements with the id #east. That's not good. Also, you cannot have two ids on the same element.

Answer (score 0):

you can use jQuery `eq()` method:

```
$('.ui-accordion:eq(0)').addClass('first') // the first ui.accordion element
```

or CSS3 `nth-child` pseudo selector:

```
.ui-accordion:nth-child(1) { the first ui.accordion element
   property: value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use two themes, one for each accordion.
When downloading [jQueryUi](http://jqueryui.com/download) click the "advanced theme settings" in the right sidebar under "Theme". Use the "CSS Scope" and "Theme Folder Name" fields. There are little help icons to explain what to do.

I have never done that so I can't tell you how easy or difficult it is.